# legend position adjustment in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I fit this horizontal legend inside the chart so that it is not cut off? Can the margins be automatically extended and the legend container left aligned with the plot? I searched a lot, but could not find a reasonable way to do this.

```
library(ggplot2)

names<-c("Bartramiaceae", "Catoscopiaceae", "Phyllodrepaniaceae","Pseudoditrichaceae","Hypopterygiaceae","Brachytheciaceae","Pterobryellaceae")

ggplot(data.frame(x=names, y=paste(names,names), shape=sample(c("one shape", "another shape"), 7,replace=T),
                  colour=sample(c("one colour", "another colour","third colour"), 7,replace=T),
                  size=sample(c(10, 100, 300),7,replace=T)), 
       aes(x=x, y=y, colour=colour, size=size, shape=shape)) + geom_point() + 
theme(legend.direction="horizontal",
      legend.box = "horizontal",
      legend.position="top", 
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
      axis.title.x=element_blank(),
      axis.title.y=element_blank()) + 
scale_y_discrete(position="right", expand=c(0.01, 0.01))

ggsave("legend_plot.png",w=8, h=8)
```

[image]

Comment: Increase the dimensions of the graphics device. (You should be using `ggsave` to export plots. It allows you specifying height and width and also the resolution for pixel graphics.)

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer to keep my plot and axis fonts the same size, but just readjust the legend. As you can see in the updated variant, there is a lot of space on the right (and I would be happy to add more), but automatic legend is still cut off.

Comment: Well, would you be happy with two rows for the legends?

Comment: You could also adjust the `legend.justification`.

Comment: legend.justification=c(0,1) in combination with legend.position=c(0,1) works, but then legend overlaps the plot area, and if I go above 1 the legend becomes invisible.

Comment: I'm really not sure what the desired outcome is here. I would just put the size and color legends on top of each other. I would also ponder alternatives to these long names on the axes.

Comment: To be able to place legend at top left. I realize that legend.justification="left" might become implemented at some time in the future. At the moment I found I can use `plot.margin = unit(c(5+1, 1, 0.5, 0.5), "lines")`, `legend.justification=c(0,1)`, `legend.position=c(0,1)` as a quick hack.